# array_intersect_key PHP array with MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, intersection

I have a simple array in PHP, say

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

and I wish to query a MYSQL database

```
[1, who]
[2, where]
[3, some]
[6, there]
[9, too]
```

I only wish to receive the rows of intersection between the PHP array and the database's indices column. So this would result in

```
[1, who]
[2, where]
[6, there]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the sql `in` keyword

```
SELECT id, title FROM tablename WHERE id IN (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

You can prepare the list of numbers using:

```
$nums = array(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7)
$sql = 'SELECT id, title FROM tablename WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $nums) . ')';
```

Edit: you can make sure your input contains only numbers with `array_filter`:

```
$nums = array_filter($nums, 'is_numeric');
```

Comment: Might want to add a giant disclaimer about the dangers of SQL injection somewhere...

Comment: Thank you very much, both of you. I knew about the IN operator, but as soon as you posted I knew what to do. I will also be sure to check the injection vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks, added array_filter to ensure $nums only contains numbers

Comment: @ Dominic Rodger: i don't see any user input, so a giant disclaimer about the dangers of SQL injection seems to be a little inappropriate here.